# FFmpeg Automatically Synchronize Audio and Video

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, synchronization, video-processing

I have two separate streams, audio (line-in, pulseaudio) and video (ip-camera, rtsp), which I would like to automatically synchronize.

The best I came up with so far is `ffmpeg` with `-itsoffset` but the offset actually varies.

> Is there any way to do this reliably automated on command-line (doesn't necessarily need to be ffmpeg)?

The camera as well as the computer run an ntp client and the input delay of pulseaudio is negligible, so this should be solvable.

Answer (score 1):

I found [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/) (`livemedia-utils` on Debian, `live-media` on Arch) that fetches a parameter `o` ... (using an arbitrary RTSP example source)

```
$ openRTSP -r rtsp://109.98.78.106
Created new TCP socket 3 for connection
Connecting to 109.98.78.106, port 554 on socket 3...
...remote connection opened
[...]
o=- 1604163122724055 1 IN IP4 109.98.78.106
[...]
```

... that seem to be the cameras UTC system time in microseconds extracted from the underlying RTC stream.

E.g.:

```
$ date -d@$( echo $(openRTSP -r rtsp://109.98.78.106 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=o=-\s)\d+' | head -n1 ) / 1000000 | bc )
Sat Oct 31 05:55:45 PM CET 2020
```

The cameras we use feature NTP functionality. I hence set up a local NTP server on the recording computer to serve as time source for the cameras.

From the delay ...

```
time_camera () {
  # Returns cameras system time as embedded in the RTC stream in nanoseconds after UNIX 0
  echo $(($(openRTSP -r ${STREAM_CAMERA} 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=o=-\s)\d+' | head -n1)000))
  }
time_local () {
  # Returns local system time in nanoseconds after UNIX 0
  date +%s%N
}
vdelay=$(($(time_local) - $(time_camera)))
```

... I can estimate how long the frame took to arrive.
You might fine tune this to your needs.

For me, it is around (900 +- 200) ms and matches the audio-video offset really well.

As mentioned above, I use Pulseaudio and can hence (regularly) set the input latency offset directly without having to mess with ffmpeg's [`-itsoffset`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) via:

```
# See: pacmd list-cards
pacmd set-port-latency-offset <card> <port> $((vdelay/1000))
```